# Не работает CSS в Firefox

Tags: firefox, css

Добрый день!

есть вот такой код:

```
background-color: -moz-linear-gradient(#013195, #1251d5, #1251d5, #013195);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#013195), to(#013195), color-stop(0.75, #1251d5));
margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 0px; /* Для Firefox 3 */
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 0px; /* Для Safari 4 и Chrome */
border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 0px; /* Для современных браузеров */
```

Но в Firefox не работает. Перечитала кучу материала, и все вроде по правилам написано.
Не уже ли есть ошибка?

Comment: Видимо, надо ``background`` вместо ``background-color``. Хотя [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503148/css3-moz-linear-gradient-not-working) и [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291484/css3-gradient-not-working-in-firefox) можно почитать больше.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что не background-color, а background-image. И можно без -moz-. Для webkit'ов нужен перфикс, да.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(#013195, #1251d5, #1251d5, #013195);
border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если это содержимое файла, то может проверить путь к файлу в теге <link />?

Comment: К сожалению там все в порядке, файл подключен и все в нем работает исправно, кроме -moz- в Firefox.

(Размышления в слух) может дело и правда не в коде и в чем-то глобальном и я не там ищу.

Comment: в firebug не пробовали посмотреть?
http://htmlbook.ru/css3-na-primerakh/lineinyi-gradient
вот тут немного другая конструкция  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefcea, #f1da36); /* Firefox 3.6+ */
помоему она более верная, здесь и направление градиента есть и всего два цвета, тогда как у Вас 4 и непонятно каки в каком месте и напрвалении они будут друг в друга перетекать

Comment: @Olga_Pro, Может [это поможет](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/qe3PW/)?

Comment: background: -moz-linear-gradient БЕЗ color сработало и закругления появились.

Спасибо всем огромное!!! 

А сайтом http://htmlbook.ru пользуюсь постоянно, лучшей шпаргалки не видела.